# Wie einen Infintiv in einem Satz benutzen?

Tags: grammar, verb

Ich bin ein Deutschlerner, also könnte meine Frage Fehler enthalten. Ich möchte wissen, wie Sätze zu übersetzen sind, wie:

> My friend Daniel likes to use a pen to write.

Meine Vermutung ist, dass der Satz übersetzt wird mit:

> → Mein Freund Daniel mag einen Kugelschreiber benutzen zu schreiben.

Ist meine Übersetzung korrekt? Wenn nicht, möchte ich die richtige Übersetzung wissen.

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] dieser Seite nehmen. In der Regel erwarten wir, dass ein Grammatikbuch befragt wird, bevor Fragen dieser Art gestellt werden. Deswegen könnte deine Frage geschlossen werden. Wenn dir dein Grammatikbuch oder eine andere Quelle nicht geholfen hat, ergänze die Frage bitte mit einem [edit]. Mehr zum Thema Schließen, Editieren, und alles, was die Seite sonst noch betrifft, findest du im [help].

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

> Mein Freund Daniel mag es, mit einem Kugelschreiber zu schreiben.

or better (but without infinitive):

> Mein Freund Daniel schreibt gerne mit einem Kugelschreiber.

Answer (score 2):

You would typically translate your sentence using a *substantiated infinitive*

> Mein Freund Daniel mag es, einen Kugelschreiber zum Schreiben zu benutzen.

(Note *Schreiben* is a substantive here, thus with capital "S")